# remove 'pub/' folder for URLs from command line

Tags: magento2, cli, bin-magento

For increased security, we configured the DocumentRoot for our Magento application to be in the `pub/` directory of the Magento installation, as described in the [official documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html).

However, there is now a problem when executing commands on the command line - or when Magento's own cron is run: whenever a URL is generated for the front end context, e.g. via

```
$this->appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation(
    $store->getId(), \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true
);

// …

$this->appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation();
```

any generated front end URL - like for product images, will still contain the `pub/` part of the URL.

The `pub/index.php` overrides the folder paths like this:

```
$params = $_SERVER;
$params[Bootstrap::INIT_PARAM_FILESYSTEM_DIR_PATHS] = [
    DirectoryList::PUB => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => ''],
    DirectoryList::MEDIA => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'media'],
    DirectoryList::STATIC_VIEW => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'static'],
    DirectoryList::UPLOAD => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'media/upload'],
];
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

i.e., it simply removes the `pub/` part from all these folder paths.

However, how can the same be done for the command line environment? (But only for the front end context.)

Magento version: `2.2.6`

Answer (score 1):

This is a more general problem of Magento, see [magento/magento2#8868](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8868).

As a workaround we simply integrated the following `RewriteRule` in our `pub/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^pub/(.*) $1
```

Of course this does not solve the underlying issue of having wrong URLs being generated from the command line.

Comment: not working for my side.